# setState doesn't work when using computed property names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to update the state according to arguments passed to the handleTime method, so i have used computed property names to perform the update (using the previous state) but the setState(within the handleTime method) doesn't work.

here is the state :

```
const sessionLength = {min: 25,
      sec: 0}
    this.state = {
      breakLength: {min: 5, sec: 0},
      sessionLength: sessionLength,
      sessionProcessed: sessionLength,
      actualState: 'Session'
    }
```

the handleTime method is responsible of updating the state and the play method is a click event handler method that call handleTime with an argument (the property name to update)

```
handleTime(str="sessionProcessed"){
    this.setState(state=>({[str]: {...state.[str], sec: state.[str].sec - 1}}));
    }
play(){
    if(typeof this.intervalId === 'undefined'){
      this.intervalId = setInterval(this.handleTime.bind(this),1000);
      this.setState({intervalId: this.intervalId});
    }
  }
```

The JSX

```
render(){
    return(
      <div class="ml-5">
        <div>{this.state.actualState}</div>
        <div><strong id="session">{this.state.sessionProcessed.min}:{this.state.sessionProcessed.sec}</strong></div>
        <div><i id="play" class="fa fa-play" onClick={this.play}></i> <i id="pause" class="fa fa-pause" onClick={this.pause}></i></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: post the codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access or set a computed key value with dot notation, you need to simply use the bracket notation for it.

e.g.

```js
handleTime(str="sessionProcessed"){
    this.setState(state=>({[str]: {...state[str], sec: state[str].sec - 1}}));
}
```

I have just removed the dot in the `state.[str]` because that would throw an error, so you are most likely not setting these properties properly.

Try changing these and see if it fixes the problem.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: it fixes the problem

Comment: Cool! Accept this as an answer if it fixes it. :)